# Standard Objects Limits

Tags: standard-objects, limits, api-28

Is there a way to know programmatically what are SOQL limits on objects?
some way that given a standard object tells that to query this object you need to use filters on the fields [x,y,z,...]?

to avoid exceptions like this:

> [MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault 
>   exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY' exceptionMessage='Implementation
>   restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id,
>   ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator']

I know [these limits are stated in the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl280/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm) but I need a on-the-fly way

Thanks,

Comment: I suspect you may want to be looking at Schema Describe methods used for [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm). This [example from the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_data_categories.htm) seems relevant to what you've cited.

Comment: There is [DescribeSObjectResult](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm).queryable and .fields filterable. However, I suspect these are not sufficient for the special case limits on Objects that you linked to. E.g. There is no description of a required filter field or limits on the number of records that will be returned based on not having the "View All Data" permission. `FilteredLookupInfo` was added in v31.0, but I haven't checked it yet.

Comment: Similar question on the Discussion Forums: [How to now the filters needed for SOQL query for Standard Objects?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AopAIAS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that, **no, you can't use the currently available meta data to determine the special query requirements** as outlined in [SOQL Limits on Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl280/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm).

Take for example, [ContentDocumentLink](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm). The special SOQL requirement here is:

> A SOQL query must filter on one of Id, ContentDocumentId, or LinkedEntityId.

There is currently no meta data in [DescribeSObjectResult](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) that can tell you that one of those fields must defined in the SOQL where clause.

You have `queryable` on DescribeSObjectResult and `filterable` on [Field](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1427375http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1427375). However, there is currently no way to know which combination of fields are required.

---

With NewsFeed the requirement is:

> No SOQL limit if logged-in user has “View All Data” permission. If not, specify a LIMIT clause of 1,000 records or fewer.

Again, there is no meta data available to indicate that a LIMIT clause is required or what the maximum value is based on the users permissions.

Comment: are those limits applied to the bulk API too?